# Regarding to installation of Gsreamer 1.8.0 in ubuntu

Tags: audio, gstreamer, ubuntu-16.04, multimedia

Can any one give me the proper guidelines for gstreamer(1.8.0) installation in Ubuntu version 16.04??
Through command line

Answer (score 0):

For installing gstreamer1.0 you can use:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-* gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-libav*
```

Depending on what are your needs, you probably are going to need other [modules](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/) that are not installed in the previous command. I would consider adding:

- gst-plugins-base
- gst-plugins-good
- gst-plugins-bad
- gst-plugins-ugly

Using next command:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

After you have installed all the plugins you can verify the installation using:

```
gst-inspect-1.0
```